# Vichuploader & API platform File is not saved

Tags: php, rest, symfony, api-platform.com, vichuploaderbundle

My problem is actually to upload file with vich. It work perfect with an other entity. But in my user's entity it doesnt work.

Vich uploader configuration :

```
vich_uploader:
db_driver: orm
mappings:
   user_cover:
       uri_prefix: /media/users
       upload_destination: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/media/users'
       namer: Vich\UploaderBundle\Naming\OrignameNamer
       delete_on_update:   true
       delete_on_remove:   true
   play_media:
       uri_prefix: /media/defis
       upload_destination: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/media/defis'
       namer: Vich\UploaderBundle\Naming\OrignameNamer
       delete_on_update:   true
       delete_on_remove:   true
```

The play_media mapping works perfectly but my problem come from **user_cover**

the part that relates in my user entity :

```
   /**
               * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
               */
               #[Groups(['read:User'] )]
               private $CoverPath;
           
                /**
                * @var File|null
                * @Assert\File(
                *     maxSize = "2048k",
                *     mimeTypes = {"image/jpeg", "image/png"},
                *     mimeTypesMessage = "Please upload a valid cover image: jpeg or png under 2048k")
                * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="play_media_test", fileNameProperty="CoverPath")
                */
                private $file;    


 /**
                * Set the value of file
                *
                *  @param File|null  $file
                *  @return User
                */ 
               public function setFile(?File $file = null) :User
               {
           
                   $this->file = $file;
           
                   if ($file instanceof File) {
                       $this->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime());
                   }
           
                   return $this;
                   
               }
```

and my controller ( no checks yet ), in theory I think I'm not supposed to update the date because the setter is already doing it and no need to use the entity manager (I tried anyway), but ...:

```
public function __invoke(Request $request)
{
    $user_data = $request->attributes->get('data');
    $user_data->setFile($request->files->get('cover'));
    $user_data->setUpdatedAt(new DateTime());
    return $user_data;
}
```

and the operation configuartion :

```
'cover' => [
                   'method' => 'POST' ,
                   'path' => 'user/{id}/cover',
                   'deserialize' => false,
                   'controller' => PostCoverUserController::class,
                   'openapi_context' => [
                       'security' => 
                       [['bearerAuth' => []]], 
                       'summary'     => 'Update the user cover image ',
                       'requestBody' => [
                           'content' => [
                               'multipart/form-data' => [
                                   'schema' => [
                                       'type' => 'object',
                                       'properties' => [
                                           'cover' => [
                                               'type' => 'string', 
                                               'format' => 'biniray'
                                           ]
                                       ]
                                   ]
                               ]
                           ]
                       ]
                       ]                                                                      
               ],
```

I reread my code several times and I don't understand why the persistence is not working as expected? however my other upload works perfectly. the api send back the answer, dd works .. only the persistence fails.
thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem came from the server's cache :
php bin / console cache:clear
;)